# How to implement a DFS to the Reddit PRAW?

Tags: depth-first-search, reddit, praw

I would like to implement a DFS to get a parent and child conversation in the Reddit API.

I'm totally lost on how to do this. Any pointers?

Comment: I don't know, but how about MoreComment instances of CommentForest object?

Comment: What do you mean by that ? i think the MoreComment only give the replies if it exist which i use by using the .replace_more, but the main problem is that the CommentForest give the comment in a parent to parent structure, but what i wanted is parent then a child, so to illustrate the way they print it in CommentForest is the following:

Parent
Parent sibling
Parent sibling
....
Child
Child siblings
....
but what i want is parent then child so the data will look like a conversation

Answer (score 3):

PRAW's `list()` method does a breadth-first traversal over the comments. https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/blob/5ee4b1820c2591117e32be45778372e7c03a5f56/praw/models/comment_forest.py#L83

If you want to make it depth-first you can do everything the same, but swap out:

```
 queue.extend(comment.replies)
```

with:

```
queue[0:0] = comment.replies
```

Comment: This is great! I needed a depth first solution and didn't want to write recursive code in my lambda functions.